# Quelle serait une meilleure façon de formuler: Il est parti en vacances à la campagne dans un chalet avec des amis

Tags: verbes, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Je sais que dans l’idéal le verbe « partir » se construit avec la préposition « pour » si l’on s’en rapporte à certains puristes. Dans la phrase en titre, le verbe concerné est construit avec « en » (au début je voulais, par souci de simplicité, me passer de *en vacances* et écrire simplement *partir dans un chalet avec des amis*). D’une manière ou d’une autre, le problème persiste car l’utilisation de *dans* ne fait que déplacer le problème d’une autre préposition, en l’occurence *en*. Je cherche donc une autre façon de tourner cette phrase sans l’emploi de *partir*. J’avais à l’idée de recourir au verbe *aller*. Or, dans une question que j’ai posée précédemment et que j’ai supprimée à la demande de quelques utilisateurs exigeants de cette plateforme, certains contributeurs prétendaient que la nouvelle phrase ainsi formée n’avait plus le même sens que la phrase originale (avec partir) du fait d’une inadéquation du temps.

> Il est allé en voyage à la campagne dans un chalet avec des amis.

Voici une autre façon que j’ai trouvée de tourner la phrase en titre:

> Il est présentement en voyage à la campagne dans un chalet avec des amis.

Comment: Une incohérence en entraîne une autre : on ne voyage pas dans un chalet, à moins qu'il s'agisse d'une roulotte, il ne voyage donc pas à la campagne, il l'a traversée pour se rendre dans le chalet. « Il est présentement/actuellement (en vacances [si le contexte l'exige]) avec des amis dans un chalet campagnard. » — La concision exige que l'on ne parle que de l'essentiel en choisissant les mots au plus près d'une situation et en les ordonnant à la façon d'un scénario basique : du plus près au plus loin, de l'extérieur vers l'intérieur, du passé au présent ou vers le futur … et l'inverse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En français moderne on n'utilise pratiquement pas « aller en voyage » ; on trouve encore cette expression mais son emploi courant remonte au 18 et 19ième siècles. ([aller en voyage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aller%20en%20voyage%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

[image]

Ce fait trouve confirmation dans l'entrée « voyage » du TLFi, qui n'inclut pas « aller en voyage » mais seulement « partir en voyage ».

> ([TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voyage)) b) Loc. verb. **Être, partir en voyage**. Être absent de, quitter son domicile pour un certain temps.
> ♦︎ Elle partit pour Rouen (...), afin d'aller chez tous les banquiers dont elle connaissait le nom. Ils étaient à la campagne ou en voyage. (Flaub., MmeBovary, t. 2, 1857, p. 149)

Remarquer dans l'exemple l'opposition entre « être à la campagne » et « (être) en voyage » ; on dit plutôt « être en voyage à » pour une ville donnée ; il y a très peu de cas où « campagne » soit utilisé.

[être en voyage à](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22est%20en%20voyage%20%C3%A0%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

[en voyage à la campagne](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22en%20voyage%20%C3%A0%20la%20campagne%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Personnellement, en raison du peu de spécificité des expressions passées en revue (bien que rapidement) je n'utiliserais ni la  phrase citée dans le titre, ni la seconde, ni « voyage » dans la troisième, et à la place de ce mot j'utiliserais « vacances ». Je changerais aussi l'ordre des compléments, comme « vacances avec des amis » est probablement un but essentiel de ce déplacement à la campagne.

- Il est présentement en vacances avec des amis dans un chalet à la campagne. ([québécois](/questions/tagged/qu%c3%a9b%c3%a9cois) usage de « présentement »)

Comment: LPH, Pourquoi pas lui dire carrément que les gens diraient tout simplement: Il est parti à la campagne ? Et aussi signaler que ce présentement est bizarre dans le language quotidien? Actuellement, il est en vacances etc.

Comment: @Lambie *Présentement* est courant en français canadien. [lan**ga**ge]

Comment: Régardez bien les exemples et l'explication pour le Québec: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=pr%c3%a9sentement&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=5239 Les exemples me semble de registre assez haut en ce qui concerne ce "vif succès". Et puis, **je trouve que la phrase est déjà bien dite dans le titre**.

Comment: @Lambie Tous les québécois avec qui j'ai eu l'occasion de discuter employaient très fréquemment *présentement* à l'oral, y compris dans des contextes parfaitement courants ou relâchés. [me semble**nt** de registre assez **élevé/soutenu**].

Comment: @Lambie Il me semble qu'il voudrait exprimer l'idée d'un seul trait, mais bien sûr, deux petites phrases ou une principale et une coordonnée (ou même deux indépendentes coordonnées) serait une alternative plus simple, cependant avec d'autre nuances et d'un autre style. ( Il est parti à la campagne ; il y passe présentement des vacances dans un chalet avec des amis. /  Il est parti  à la campagne pour y passer ses/des vacances dans un chalet avec des amis. /  Il est parti à la campagne, il  y passe des vacances dans un chalet avec des amis. (1/4)

Comment: @Lambie Je n'ai rien signalé parce que, si le mot « présentement » ne m'est  pas  familier, il a cependant un sens tout désigné et donc il acquiert, en quelque sorte, une certaine légitimité. Mais maintenant que l'on me fait la remarque, je ne crois pas que je devrais signaler quoi que ce soit : on traite sur ce site deux branches de la vieille langue française (on s'attarde aussi sur le « belge » et le « suisse », qui présentent moins de variation), et j'ai appris dernièrement que même dans des questions banalisées, certains utilisateurs, comme user Jean Lou Frenette, (2/4)

Comment: Lambie  s'expriment naturellement en québecois, **et** tiennent à préserver dans leur interaction l'unité de cette version particulière du français qu'ils utilisent. En conséquence, il me semble qu'il n'est plus question de compter seulement avec le français utilisé en France, mais qu'il devient nécessaire de s'en tenir à la trame commune (ce que l'on peut faire souvent parce qu'elle est très importante). On est d'ailleurs averti par les tags « canada », quand il y en a un, que l'on doit connaitre suffisamment la partie québécoise du langage avant de s'intéresser (3/4)

Comment: @Lambie à la question de près. Cependant, pour  l'utilisateur non averti, il manque une indication, un peu comme celles que des utilisateurs mettent au début ou à la fin  de leur questions (locuteur non natif, demande d'explications en termes simple, etc.) ; quelque chose comme « parler québécois » serait finalement reconnu comme la marque de textes dont les apparentes irrégularités peuvent en fait être normales parce qu'il s'agit de la variété québécoise du français. On serait alors plus apte à ne faire de corrections qu'à bon escient. (4/4)

Answer (score 2):

La phrase originale ***Il est parti en vacances à la campagne dans un chalet avec des amis*** est grammaticalement correcte mais son style est loin d'être parfait à cause de l'accumulation de quatre compléments circonstanciels successifs.

Si ton objectif est de ne pas utiliser *partir*, il suffit de le retirer de ta phrase et d'y insérer une pause à l'aide d'une virgule :

> **Il est en vacances à la campagne, dans un chalet avec des amis.**

En effet, *être parti en vacances* signifie bien ici *être en vacances*, d'autant plus que tu as bien indiqué que l'action n'était pas passée (*présentement*) et précisé le lieu de séjour (*dans un chalet*).

Pour ce qui est de tes deux propositions :

1. Il est allé en voyage à la campagne dans un chalet avec des amis.
2. Il est présentement en voyage à la campagne dans un chalet avec des amis.

La 1. présente un problème de timing. On a l'impression que la personne a terminé ses vacances. Ce qui ne correspond pas au sens attendu.

La 2. est plus lourde encore que la phrase originale en raison de la présence d'un cinquième complément circonstanciel. On est essoufflé après l'avoir lue ;-)

Comment: être en vacances n'est pas pareil que partir en vacances.

Comment: @Lambie https://www.academie-francaise.fr/pareil-que-pour-pareil

Comment: @Lambie La phrase d'origine ne dit pas *Il **part** en vacances* mais *il **est parti** en vacances*. Quand on est parti en vacances, on est en vacances, et la probabilité est plus grande qu'on soit arrivé sur son lieu de villégiature plutôt qu'on soit encore en train de se déplacer. Si je dis "Il est parti une semaine au ski", c'est de la destination que je parle, pas du voyage.

Comment: rappel: "en l’occurence en. Je cherche donc une autre façon de tourner cette phrase sans l’emploi de partir. J’avais à l’idée de recourir au verbe aller".  sans changer le sens, j'imagine.

Comment: @Lambie L'utilisation d'aller n'aurait pas respecté le sens original. Je viens d'ajouter ce point à ma réponse.

Answer (score 0):

**Il est parti en vacances|| à la campagne|| dans un chalet|| avec des amis.**

La phrase est excellente.

- partir en vacances= locution idiomatique
- partir en voyage d'affaires=pareil
- partir en voyage de noces=pareil
- partir en vacances **à la campagne, à la mer, à la montagne, au ciel [blague]**
- [les lieux ou endroits] dans un chalet, dans une ferme, dans un monastère, dans une île

avec des amis: Il aurait quand même pu partir avec son petit klebs. [blague]

**Personnellement**, je ne dirais pas que quelqu'un est "en voyage à la campagne", ni "il est allé en voyage à [lieu]". Pour moi, c'est partir en voyage.

Partir en voyage autour du monde.
Partir en voyage [loin de là où on se trouve] en Italie, aux Etats-Unis, au Canada, en Chine, au Brésil.

Même quand on vit dans un pays très grand comme le Canada, si on dit partir à la campagne, on comprends que *la personne vit quelque part dans une ville* et va à "une" campagne qui se situe à une distance raisonnable de cette agglomération. Et pas qu'elle va traverser tout un pays pour y arriver    à cette campagne.
On habite en ville/à la campagne.

Si, par exemple, on habite à Toronto et on va jusqu'en Saskatchewan, on part "en voyage en Saskatchewan pour faire du camping".

Voici le genre d'analyse qu'il faut faire à mon avis. On découpe la phrase en différents segments et on regarde si cela marche ou pas.

Je ne pense pas que l'on puisse faire autrement dans une analyse de ce type que de faire une comparaison avec le langage intériorisé dont on dispose soi-même.

-